# For two 1D arrays that contain different numbers of elements, how to delete elements from one so it is the same size as the other?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am using Python to process large data files.  I first get data from several different files and store it.  An example of extracting data from one file is provided below for "time" data.  Then I plot the data (like "time") against data from other files or perform calculations.

```
skip        = int(input('\nSkip how many steps?\n'))
datai       = loadtxt(filei,skiprows=(1+skip))
time        = datai[:,0]
```

My problem is that arrays (like "time") created from distinct files often do not contain the same number of elements.  So that leads to errors when I try to perform calculations or make plots. For example:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (128471,) (116102,)
```

Does anyone know how to delete elements from a 1D array so that it's the same length as a reference array (like "time")?  I know how to cut n elements off a particular array, but not how to do something like "figure out the length of 'time" and then make the array 'temperature' the same length," at least not efficiently.

It's important that elements are only removed from the ends of the arrays--i.e., so that all elements in all arrays stay in their original positions (element "2" of "time" is the same as element "2" of "temperature").

My apologies; this seems like something that has probably been asked before, but I have so far had no success in finding a solution online, maybe because I'm not familiar with the appropriate search terms (I'm not an experienced Python user).

Comment: bigger_array = bigger_array[:116102]

Comment: It would be a simple question to answer, but I just want to clarify: What are you suggesting to do with the rest of values that don't fit the reference length of array?

Comment: Thank you both for your replies.  progalgo, thanks for checking.  I'm going to ignore/throw away the values that don't fit the reference array length.  I'm running simulations and a frustrating problem is that they often end before all of the output files are printed.

Comment: Florian, thanks.  Your solution works (I'm embarrassed to have asked--it's so simple).  If you want to add it as a reply to my question, I can mark it as correct.  Something odd though, is that I have to input the size of the reference array as a number--like you've written it.  For example, I can't get the length of the reference array by doing bigger_array = bigger_array[:len(smaller_array)]. When I do this, the size of bigger_array doesn't change.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: What are exact types of object you refer to as "arrays"? Are those Python lists? Are those some kind of lazy streams? File-like objects? Generators?

Comment: progalgo, my understanding (again, not an experienced Python user) is that "numpy.loadtxt," which loads data from a text file, simply calls the loaded data "arrays." They don't seem to be lists.  I say this because for doing certain operations using these arrays, I have had to use "np.asarray()" to convert other objects from lists to arrays. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that answer is what you'r looking for, but it should work:

```
x = [2,4,3,2,6,4,4,4,3,3,3]

y = [3,4,6]

y.append(7)

z = []

for i in range(len(y)):
    z.append(x[i])

print(z)
print(y)
```

result: 
[2, 4, 3, 2],
[3, 4, 6, 7]

It wouldn't be less efficient than the x = x[:len(y)], but since y's size changes during the program run, it will not allocate the extra memory and therefore it would leave x to be size of 3. I assume that is the reason it does not works for you, because the interpreter doesn't know the smaller_array size when the program starts.